# Retrieve images from iMessage app iOS

Tags: ios, imessage

I want to know if it's possible to retrieve images programmatically from `iMessage` app, which are not saved in camera app. I know it is not possible for a third party app to access the resources of native app. I just want to make sure that it is valid for iMessage app too.

Comment: I think you pretty much already answered your question. No it's not possible as you do not have access to content of other apps.

Comment: Exactly Apple has been keeping those restrictions for a long time. I just want to make sure that apple is still sticking with their those restrictions.

Comment: App sandboxing is in place precisely to prevent malicious apps from stealing the user's data without their consent.

Comment: @NicolasMiari There is no way to get the consent of user for accessing images from their iMessage app as apple doesn't provide any provision for a developer to ask the user.

Comment: I assume you meant to type "no way". Of course there isn't. The app should ask the user to 1. Save their photos from messages to the Camera Roll, and 2. Grant the app access to the Photo Library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple doesn't allow this. You cannot access messages or the media received with that message unless the images are saved to gallery.

Even if you do this somehow, Apple wouldn't allow it to be in the App Store.